# Node JS keep getting Failed to load resource error message

Tags: node.js

I am currently testing out a node.js application and have tried to add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/formalize.css" />
<script src="assets/js/jquery.formalize.js"></script>
```

to my code but keeping getting the error message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 

http://localhost:3000/assets/css/formalize.css

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 

http://localhost:3000/assets/js/jquery.formalize.js
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong? Here is my code so far (in app.js)

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.htm');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('send message', function(data) {
        io.sockets.emit('new message', data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add the `express.static` middleware to your `app` and make it point to your directory with static assets.

For example, if you directory structure is set up like this:

```
app.js
index.htm
  static
    assets
      js
        jquery.formalize.js
      css
        formalize.css
```

You would specify your static asset directory like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
```

And reference your files in your html file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/formalize.css"/>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery.formalize.js"></script>
```