# Node.js. Why is the page cannot load css and javascript file?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

i have created a node.js server. When i entered the localhost using port 3000, it displayed text only without css or javascript. I have tried several solutions that have worked on others. but they didn't worked for me.

[Node JS keep getting Failed to load resource error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775944/node-js-keep-getting-failed-to-load-resource-error-message)

[static files with express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434001/static-files-with-express-js)

[Can not get CSS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395742/can-not-get-css-file)

my file order is like this

```
server.js
index.html
 public
  css
   style.css
```

This is the code for the server

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));
app.listen(3000);
```

These are the errors

```
GET http://localhost:3000/ [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 11ms]
GET http://localhost:3000/public/css/demo.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 10ms]
GET http://localhost:3000/public/css/themes/popclip.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 10ms]
GET http://localhost:3000/public/css/reveal.min.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 19ms]
GET http://localhost:3000/public/css/theme/default.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 12ms]
GET http://localhost:3000/public/css/jquery.dropdown.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 11ms]
GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 10ms]
GET http://localhost:3000/public/js/jquery.min.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 29ms]
GET http://localhost:3000/public/js/jquery.popline.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 28ms]
GET http://localhost:3000/public/js/plugins/jquery.popline.link.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 28ms]
```

Comment: show your `index.html`.

Answer (score 10):

This:

```
__dirname + 'public'
```

Should be:

```
__dirname + '/public'
```

Also it looks like your paths in your html/css may not be correct since `__dirname + '/public'` will be your *root*. So unless you have a directory `__dirname + '/public/public'` you will have to change the paths in your html/css.

Answer (score 10):

Problem solved.

The problem was in my index.html file. Originally I thought that when i created a new folder and put in all the css and js files there, I needed to add the 'public' in all the src. Like this

```
<script src="public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="public/js/jquery.popline.js"></script>
```

But instead, I just have to do it without the 'public' folder like this

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.popline.js"></script>
```

and add '/' to the `__dirname + 'public'` to `__dirname + '/public'` like [mscdex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2050455/mscdex) suggested.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few items, I just wanted to list my working results in case it helps anyone else.

Lines of code I had tried but failed to get working for me:

```
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
```

My project was in folder 'project' which contained 'public' folder, 'views' folder, and server.js file. Node, Express and Handlebars were used to render the pages. In 'public' was a folder 'css' where my style.css file was saved.

On server.js I used

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

On my main.handlebars file in 'views' > 'layouts' I had in the  section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

With those in place, starting up a local instance worked and no '404' error message when loading the stylesheet.