# Failed to load resource 404 (Not Found) - file location error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm building an Angular 2 app which I just upgraded to Net Core RC2. Prior to the upgrade, my webpage would display just fine, but now I am getting errors in my Chrome Dev Tools console:

```
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found): 
http://localhost:5000/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js

    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found): 
http://localhost:5000/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css
```

I have bootstrap in my package.json file with version 3.3.6. I installed it with an **npm install** command. It installed properly in my Visual Studio project. The files are located at:

**project -> node_modules -> bootstrap -> dist -> js -> boostrap.min.js**

and

**project -> node_modules -> bootstrap -> dist -> css -> boostrap.min.css**

My gulpfile has this section:

```
var config = {
libBase: 'node_modules',
lib: [
    require.resolve('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'),
    require.resolve('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'),
    path.dirname(require.resolve('bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff')) + '/**',
    require.resolve('jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'),
    require.resolve('chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js')
]
```

};

I'm also seeing a reference to bootstrap.min.js in a _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Homepage WebDev</title>
    <base href="/" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />

</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to web development so I'm not completely sure what's happening. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: if you put these urls in the address bar, you can see the files or gives you an 404?

Comment: I don't get any errors but I don't see the files either (they're just black webpages). I only get errors when I navigate to http://localhost:5000. Other files like my main.bundle.js do show up however.

Comment: Maybe you could take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775944/node-js-keep-getting-failed-to-load-resource-error-message I hope this is a helpful article/question

Comment: It seems like all files that are located within the 'lib' folder cannot be found.

Comment: This is actually happening to me the first time the map loads. Any idea on why this would be. I have bootstrap included in the "head" of my index file and google maps in a script tag just before the closing <body> tag

Comment: @RyanHamblin For me the problem was that a 'lib' folder containing the necessary files/resources wasn't being generated. I had a webpack.config.js file that contained a script command that auto-generated the 'lib' folder. I used a command prompt to run the command and generate the folder - after that it worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the path you gave doesn't have any bootstrap files in them.

```
href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Make sure the files exist over there , else point the files to the correct path, which should be in your case

```
href="~/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Turns out there was a custom command in my webpack.config.js file that ran a script to auto-generated the 'lib' folder.